# Want to switch to Ubuntu from Windows 10

Tags: laptop

Please help me with steps as i want to use Ubuntu and remove Windows 10 from my lappy. Thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=change+window+to+ubuntu&oq=change+window+to+ubuntu&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4405j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: This site prefers users to have at least had a go (a step or two beyond just using a search engine), then coming here with details of what you did, and your error/problem for us to help.  A simple search comes up with https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 , https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation and lots more..

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the thing, it's still not a good idea to switch to **Ubuntu** from **Windows 10**, if you just know nothing about **Ubuntu** and how it works. Still obviously you can switch to **Ubuntu** if you have high eager to learn it. My recommendation is - Try Ubuntu in a *virtual box* or install Ubuntu *alongside* Windows 10.

I can show you some steps to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10.
Just go to the [link](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) and read through the whole process without starting it. If you understand everything the proceed.

**Disclaimer**: You may need someone well known about Ubuntu installing system if you find the upper link reading hard to understand.

And heads up for you if you want to stick with Ubuntu or any kind of Linux try [searching online for your issues](https://www.google.com/). It's your best friend.

Also, you can [ask smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). It's helpful for answer-er to understand your question.

Comment: Getting Ubuntu to look and work as well as Windows can be quite involving. You can also try Ubuntu for a while from your USB disk. You need some strong motivation to use Ubuntu, like the need to learn it for your career or perhaps you can't afford Windows license, because you'll often encounter bumps that will push you back to the ease and familiarity of Windows. So as @Jairul says, it's better to install the two OS's side-by-side as you transition.